# Новое окно или слой? Swing

Tags: java, swing

Пишу игру "Балда" для двух игроков на Swing. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: при нажатии "новая игра" есть три варианта перехода к самой игре - 1) добавить новый слой и на нем все рисовать, 2)скрыть текущие элементы и отрисовать новые, 3) текущее окно скрыть, а новое добавить. Какой вариант наиболее оптимальный?
п.с. свинг изучаю третий день=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Вы сыграли одну игру, вторую - закрыли приложение. Нормально. А что будет, когда решите устроить марафон на ночь? Не надо строить дом на крыше другого дома.
2) Скрыть текущие элементы это то же самое, что и рисовать сверху. Они всё равно будут в памяти, а зачем?
3) Скрыть текущее окно более оптимальный вариант. **Попробуйте сделать каждую новую игру на новый поток, и после нажатия на "Новая игра" пусть прошлый поток закрывается.**